# Using Sklearn's feature hasher

Tags: python, hash, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to train a binary classifier

My training data consists of paths in a graph where each node has a name.

So for example, here is something that could be in my training data:

["thing_a","cats_are_cool","blah"] could belong to class 0.

Order matters. So ["node_a","node_b","node_c"] != ["node_c","node_b","node_a"]

Since my paths can be different lengths, I am thinking I need to hash my training data because padding shorter paths with zeroes sounds dangerous. I want to use sci kit learn's feature hasher. In the following example, the test variable consists of three paths:

```
h = FeatureHasher(n_features=2**20,non_negative=True,input_type = 'string')
test = [["unit_a","unit_b","unit_c"],["unit_c","unit_d","unit_c"],["unit_f","unit_aa"]]
X_new = h.transform(test)
print X_new.nonzero()
```

which gives me:

```
(array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2], dtype=int32), array([ 211168,  221554,  875718,  211168, 1009892,  765479,  838855], dtype=int32))
```

I think the hasher is making "unit_a" = 211168, "unit_b" = 221554,...etc. but that is not what I want. I want the first path to have a number and the second path to have a number,etc. What can I do to achieve this?

Once again, order of items in the path matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reshape `test`:

```
In [608]:
from sklearn.feature_extraction import FeatureHasher
h = FeatureHasher(n_features=2**20,non_negative=True,input_type = 'string')
test = [["unit_a","unit_b","unit_c"],["unit_c","unit_d","unit_c"],["unit_f","unit_aa"]]
test = [[','.join(x) for x in test]] # join and reshape
X_new = h.transform(test)
test,X_new.nonzero()

Out[608]:
([['unit_a,unit_b,unit_c', 'unit_c,unit_d,unit_c', 'unit_f,unit_aa']],
 (array([0, 0, 0], dtype=int32), array([231648, 410028, 497899], dtype=int32)))
```

I might suggest you keep it simple, though, with:

```
In [610]:
test = [["unit_a","unit_b","unit_c"],["unit_c","unit_d","unit_c"],["unit_f","unit_aa"]]
test_hash = [hash(tuple(x))%2**20 for x in test]
test_hash

Out[610]:
[736062, 345078, 521256]
```